# Are the ".NET CLR Memory category" PerformanceCounters the only way to determine heap sizes?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, heap-memory

For debugging purposes I am interested in periodically logging information related to .NET heap sizes (gen 0, gen 1, gen2, large object) along with other operations that the program is performing to get an idea of what a user might be doing that is causing more memory to be used.

I see that the ".NET CLR Memory category" PerformanceCounters can be used to determine the various heap sizes.  For this to work, you need to specify the "instance" for which process to monitor.  In my case, I would like to monitor the information for my own process.  Further there are likely to be many processes running this same executable name and users on the same server may be starting and exiting these executables throughout the day.

I have found this page [Rick Strahl's Weblog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Sep/27/Capturing-Performance-Counter-Data-for-a-Process-by-Process-Id) that explains how to determine the "instance" given a process ID, which in my case would be the from the current process.  However in the comments on that page, it seems that any process with the same executable name that exits can cause "instance" names to change.

Let's say my application name is "myApp" and the instance names are "myApp" for process ID 0, "myApp#1" for process ID 1 and "myApp#2" for process ID 2.  Using Rick's Strahl's technique I could determine that the "instance" for my process ID (process ID 1) is currently "myApp#1".  I start periodically logging heap size information for my process with the "myApp#1" instance name, but then process ID 0 for the current "myApp" instance exits.  I suppose the renaming could work like this "myApp#1" is renamed to "myApp" (now proccess ID 1) and "myApp#2" is renamed to "myApp#1" (now process ID 2).  If that is the case and my code is not somehow paying attention to the instances being renamed, I imagine that I am going to start logging information for process ID 2 instead of my process ID (process ID 1) if I only determined my "instance" once during program initialization.

With this potential "instance" renaming, it seems like using the PerformanceCounters to determine heap sizes for my current process can get complicated.

So the first question that comes to mind is: Are PerformanceCounters the only way to determine the heap sizes for .NET?  Or is there some other .NET API that will get me the same information in an easier way.

If on the other hand, PerformanceCounters are the only way to get the heap sizes, what would be the best approach to dealing with "instance" renaming when a process exits?  After all constantly reevaluating the "instance" for a process ID might be time consuming.

EDIT: To give some background, I had recently fixed some memory leaks that one of our clients encountered after upgrading to a new version of our software.  I used the ANTS Memory Profiler to track down the memory leaks and fix them.  I am aware of how to use a memory profiler to fix problems.  Now a couple of things come to mind:

1. Why not try to create some automated tests that can look for the presence of constantly increasing memory usage over time which would indicate a change in the code caused memory leaks.  That way we can find and can fix memory leaks bugs before they get out to a customer.  Considering that I just fixed fixed some memory leaks, I am aware of how to create a test case for the bugs I just fixed.
   Being able to log memory usage for that test case, would allow checking the logs to see if the memory usage constantly goes up or stays stable for the test case.
2. Our testing did not uncover the case that the customer found.  There was a call with the customer to figure out exactly what one particular user was doing differently than the other users that was encountering the memory leaks.  So it seems it could be useful to be able to turn on some debug level of logging for a user that could collect information about what the user is doing in addition to what is going on with the heap sizes when that user is encountering a memory leak.  That seems like a useful tool, as the logging could potentially help us figure out what the user is doing without having to get that user to demonstrate what they are doing with the software that is causing the problem.

EDIT 2: Searching a bit more I have found some other ways of determining how much memory a process uses:

1. System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64
2. GC.GetTotalMemory()
3. Use the [Profiling API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (I guess tools like ANTS Memory Profiler uses this API).  However this does not seem to be useful for a process to log its own memory usage since the API is unmanaged, is not meant to profile its own process and not intended to used from managed code.

Using PrivateMemorySize64 and/or GetTotalMemory() do not provide the finer granularity of memory used as the PerformanceCounters can show, but are easier to use than the PerformanceCounters and do not require figuring out the "instance" name and dealing with "instance" names changing.

Comment: Why would you need to know this?  The way C# manages memory is an implementation detail.  If you want to know how much memory your program is using overall, look at the Diagnostic Tools window in Visual Studio while your program is running.

Comment: Yeah you need a memory profiler, doing this your self is going to be a waste of your time (although you might get a humble sense of achievement after reinventing the wheel... badly)